# aws cloudfront Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs

i published a website on cloudfront.
i set the cache to be 0.(cloudfront)
done invalidations(cloudfront)

the issue occurs to specific users that trying to access the website.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at main.XXXXX.js
whenever the user that encounter this issue does ctrl f5 it gets fixed. the problem is that it re-occur after a while. how can i solve it from the root cause? i cant ask my users to ctrl f5 every time

i tried to disable the cache and enable the cache, tried with and without invalidations. nothing helped
[package.json browserlist configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wHq2.jpg)

[error message on site console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBVuH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront Invalidation works for me every time.
ensure you are invalidating the correct paths and that the invalidation process is completing successfully. You might also want to check the distribution's "Invalidations" tab in the CloudFront console for any errors.

Also Ensure that your origin server is sending appropriate Cache-Control headers. For static assets, you may want to set longer cache durations, while dynamic content (like your main-xxxxx) should have `no-cache` or short cache durations.